# renaming email template file will effect the magento functionality

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

i don't want to send the `newsletter subscription success email` and `welcome new suer email with password`. I want to ask rename the email template name is better or i have to override the `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber`.

Comment: Overriding is better way. Why Magento search a template that does not exist.

Comment: @AkhilGupta magento search for template not there it will not send the email?

Comment: you mean instead of sending subscription success mail, you need to send some other mail ?

Comment: No, will not send the mail but will through the exception.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy no i don't want to send any other. i don't want to override because it is long list and i want quick solution for that.

Comment: @QaisarSatti for me, your question is not clear. it appears like you want to send an email with user-email & password instead of an email with subscription success message. Am I right  ?

Comment: @RajeevKTomy i want to disable both email. but i don't want to override the any model for that.

Comment: @AkhilGupta no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont wan't rewrite the model class and still need to do this in proper way, then you can rely on my approach.

### What you need to do

You need to listen to the event `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` and your observer method should look like this.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function disableNewsletterMails($observer)
    {
        /** Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber **/
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $subscriber->setImportMode(true);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

### Why this works

If you inspect `subscribe()` method in `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber` model class, you can see that, email will be sent after `save()` action completed. Hence our observer code will executed before email processing happens.

In our observer, we are just setting the data `import_mode` to `true`. The importance of this code can be seen in `sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()` method which is actually sending success mail.

```
public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
{
    if ($this->getImportMode()) {
        return $this;
    }
    ...
}
```

This means if `import_mode` value is `true`, then it will eventually come out from email sending process.

Answer (score 1):

The renaming  `email template` is not affecting the Magento functionality. I rename the `app/locale/en_us/template/email/newsletter_subscr_success.html` and Magento is stop sending the `newsletter success` email without any error.

Comment: this works. but I dont feel this as a proper approach. Hence I put an answer. Have a look